# how to create sagemaker pipeline definition file via aws cli?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

is it possible to create a sagemaker pipeline definition file via aws cli? based on the docs here, https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/abalone_build_train_deploy/sagemaker-pipelines-preprocess-train-evaluate-batch-transform.ipynb
one can create pipeline steps via jupyter notebook and create a pipeline object and then execute it via jupyter notebook. essentially, all the steps are documented in some json file. can i simply create that json file locally or via cli and then execute it  via aws cli from my local machine , for example

```
aws sagemaker update-pipeline --pipeline-name $PIPELINE_NAME --role-arn $ROLE_ARN --pipeline-definition "$pipeline_definition_json"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the pipeline and its steps using the Sagemaker SDK. Once you have this you can export the JSON (pipeline.definition()) and later use it with the cli to create or update.